# Run an external step in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a test suite that runs externally and I would like to add that as a step in my job and return a success/failure from the external job back to GitHub actions. Is there a way to achieve that currently or could someone point me to the correct section in the docs that explains this?

Comment: If you already have a way to trigger the external step (for example, with a CURL command), an option could be to use a dispatch event from the Github API to trigger the workflow back after your test suite, with a success/failure field filled, from the external step.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Would that create a new job or send the response back to the existing one?

Comment: You would have a new workflow run, but it would be a sequence of the previous one, and the implementation can be in the same job. I've done something similar using 2 different repositories with Github Actions, triggering a repository dispatch or workflow dispatch event ([if you want to have a look it's here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/04-dispatch-event-workflow.yml)), but the callback could actually be from anywhere, as long as you can call the Github API from there.

Comment: The second repository workflow (doing the ping pong with the first one) can be found [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/ritchie-formulas-scheduler-demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/6-formulas-scheduler-remote-dispatch.yml).

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out! But in my case it will be just a single repo with 2 workflows right?

Comment: If your external job can be on the same repository, in another workflow, yes :)